# The image exceed to the padding area of the parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, responsive

I'm trying to make thumbnails. Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="product-preview">
    <div data-img-url="images/image7.jpg" class="p-thumbnail">
        <img src="images/image7.jpg" />
    </div><div data-img-url="images/image8.jpg" class="p-thumbnail">
        <img src="images/image8.jpg" />
    </div><div data-img-url="images/image9.jpg" class="p-thumbnail">
        <img src="images/image9.jpg" />
    </div><div data-img-url="images/image10.jpg" class="p-thumbnail">
        <img src="images/image10.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.product-preview {
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
.product-preview .p-thumbnail {
    height: 120px;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.p-thumbnail img {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

How to fix so that the the img will not exceed to the padding area of .p-thumbnail? I attach a photo below, hope I make clear enough so that someone can understand what I'm trying to say! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because overflow property will only hide the child of the element from the border and outwards. If you want to limit your image not to exceed the content box, you have to put some inner container or make the image to contain.

**First Option**

```
<div data-img-url="images/image7.jpg" class="p-thumbnail">
    <div class="imgcover">
       <img src="images/image7.jpg" />
    </div>
</div><div data-img-url="images/image8.jpg" class="p-thumbnail">
    <div class="imgcover">
       <img src="images/image7.jpg" />
    </div>
</div><div data-img-url="images/image9.jpg" class="p-thumbnail">
    <div class="imgcover">
       <img src="images/image7.jpg" />
    </div>
</div><div data-img-url="images/image10.jpg" class="p-thumbnail">
    <div class="imgcover">
       <img src="images/image7.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

With additional CSS

```
div.imgcover{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want your image to be centered on the imgcover div you can use

```
.p-thumbnail{
    position: relative;
}

.p-thumbnail img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

**Second Option**

Change the style of the image to this to emulate object-fit: contain

```
.product-preview .p-thumbnail {
    height: 120px;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.p-thumbnail img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: But why does the img exceed the padding of the parent?

Comment: @hayley because the way HTML works that overflowing content will not be cut by the padding, it will start to cut from the border and outward. If you want the image not go through the padding, you have to contain it inside the content-box of the parent either using max-width and max-height to 100% or using container.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is

```
.product-preview img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* instead of height: 100%; */
}
```

and try to used images with same width and height so you dont have any problem

Comment: My case is that I cannot make sure the size of the images that the users upload. In order to fit the case that the image is vertical so I set height to 100 percent.

Answer (score 0):

The very first simple solution that comes to mind is that you can use a `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element. 
But if you want your image to fully be visible on the thumbnail you can use this codes to your image tag 
`{
 width: 100%;
object-fit: cover; 
}`